# Sharepoint publishing portal compatability with IE

Tags: master-page, custom-masterpage, branding, html5

After I redesigned the publishing masterpage on sharepoint foundation 2010 and everything works great on chrome and IE 11 when I checked on older versions of ie : 8 , 9 , 10
The homepage loads for 2 secs and then all disappears and the top part above the navigation remains .. I use Html5 and jquery for the new design 
And in compatability meta tag ie=11 when I change it to 10 or 9 it stops working on all ie versions .... any ideas ??

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 is newer than these versons of Internet explorer so it is not supported. Not fully anyway.

You may want to use Javascript libraries to enable support for older browsers like HTML5shiv at https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv/

You may also want to take a look  at http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-older-browsers-and-the-shiv/

Depending on your master page it could be easy or downright impossibe to make it work.

However this is not a SharePoint issue.